# Iterating with ls and checking with -f doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a piece of code that should work, but it doesn't.
I want to iterate through the files and subdirectories of directories given in the command line and see which one of them is a file. The program never entries in the if statement.

```
for i in $@;do
    for j in `ls $i`;do
       if [ -f $j ];then
          echo $j is a file!
       fi
    done
done
```

Comment: too many issues to point them all... see  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs , use http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `find "$@" -type f`

Comment: [_not relevant to the question_]; A good practice also would be to make the variable names self-explanatory, instead of `i`, `j`, you could use `myFolder`, `myFile`, etc, to improve readability of your code

Comment: @WilliamPursell  Depending on the intent, you may need to control the depth of the search `find` performs, as the OP code does not recurse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things can go wrong with your approach.  Do it this way.

```
for i in "$@" ; do
    for j in "$i"/* ; do
       if [ -f "$j" ]; then
          echo "$j is a regular file!"
       fi
    done
done
```

Changes :

- Quoted the `"$@"` to avoid problems with file paths containing spaces, newlines.
- Used shell globbing in the inner loop, as parsing `ls` output is not a good idea (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- Double-quoted variable expansion inside the test, once again to allow for files with spaces, newlines.
- Added "regular" in the output, because this is what this specific test operator tests for (e.g. will exclude files that correspond to devices, FIFOs, not just directories).

You could simplify a bit if you are so inclined :

```
for i in "$@" ; do
    for j in "$i"/* ; do
       ! [ -f "$j" ] || echo "$j is a regular file!"
    done
done
```

If you want to use `find`, you need to make sure you only list files at a depth of one level (or else the results could be different from your code).  You can do it this way :

```
find "$@" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo "{} is a file" \;
```

Please note that this will still be a bit different, as globbing (by default) excludes files that start with a period.  Adding `shopt -s dotglob` to the loop-based solution would allow globbing to consider all files, which should then make both solutions operate on the same files.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll be better off using `find`:

```
find $@ -type f
```